# Text extraction using cell reference

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I have names in Cell B5 and B6 as follows:

"ABC",

"ABC/1000/CE"

I need the extracted value in Cell N6 which should be "ABC/"
When I am using this formula directly in the Sheet it works fine but when I use this in Excel VBA then the whole name appears.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("/", B6)), LEFT(B6, SEARCH("/", B6) - 1) & "/",B6)
```

VBA code:

```
ws.Cells(i, "N").Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("" / "", INDIRECT(""" & cellAddress & """))), LEFT(INDIRECT(""" & cellAddress & """), SEARCH("" / "", INDIRECT(""" & cellAddress & """)) - 1) & "" / "", INDIRECT(""" & cellAddress & """))"
```

Strangely, when the name doesn't contain "/" the VBA code works. So B5 is properly extracted.

What am I doing wrong?

Please help.

Comment: The issue might the extra spaces in your formula: Try `ws.Cells(i, "N").Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""/"", INDIRECT(""" & cellAddress & """))), LEFT(INDIRECT(""" & cellAddress & """), SEARCH(""/"", INDIRECT(""" & cellAddress & """)) - 1) & ""/"", INDIRECT(""" & cellAddress & """))"`. Note: changed occurances of `"" / ""` to `""/""`

Comment: I suspect you don't even need the `INDIRECT`s. Try `ws.Cells(i, "N").Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""/"", " & cellAddress & ")), LEFT(" & cellAddress & ", SEARCH(""/"", " & cellAddress & ") - 1) & ""/""," & cellAddress & ")"`

Comment: Try `ws.Cells(i, "N").Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""/"", B6)), LEFT(B6, SEARCH(""/"", B6) - 1) & ""/"",B6)"`.

Comment: @ Super Symmetry, Just left my office. Will let you know tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij I suspect OP wants a more dynamic cell reference, not hard-coded to B6.

Comment: I'd suggest: `ws.Cells(i, "N").Formula = "=LEFT(" & cellAddress & ",SEARCH(""/""," & cellAddress & "&""/"")-1)"` You possibly also don't need the loop or variable.

Comment: Thanks @ Super Symmetry, Your both formulas worked. I picked the 2nd one which does away with the use of INDIRECT.